# How to mask different URLs defined as smarty/php value?

Tags: php, .htaccess, smarty, masking, cloaking

I am a beginner to programming that said I've checked many tutorials and websites for a potential answer to my question.

I would like to ask you how can I hide affiliate links (many of which are different) that are dynamic. For example it appears as `href="{$some_content.text}"`.

I would like to make them pretty like: `http://example.com/product?id=`

I know how to redirect through htaccess permanent link, but it's much more complicated when I am not able to define URL.

Any ideas? Thanks!